# Directed unweighed graph with adjacency file in C

Tags: c, graph, shortest-path, adjacency-list

My goal is to create a program in C that will take an adjacency list file and the arguments given. The program I want to make will go from argv[1] to argv[2] using the list and then display the shortest path possible. So far all I have is some notes for what the code will look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("adj.data", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        //if file is not in directory
        printf("File was not found!\n Try again when you have a valid file!\n");
        return;
    }

    int i;
    while (fgets(buffer,buff,file) != NULL) {
        //while still able to read from file  
        if (sscanf(buffer, "%d %d", &from[i], &to[i]) == 2) {
            grab edge i
            set arrayi = {from[i], to[i]}
            addtolist(from[i])
            //adds number to list if not already on it
            //so we can check if the arguments are on the list later
            addtolist(to[i])

            if (argc==3) { //else give error and exit
                checklist(argv[1])
                checklist(argv[2])
                //checks list from earlier to make sure arguments are there,
                //else give error and end program
                //create queue starting with argv[1]
                findshort(argv[1], argv[2], 0)
            }
        } else {    
            printf("File does not meet requirements!\n");
            fclose(file);
            return;
        }  
    }  
}

findshort(int f, int t, count) //finds the shortest link from f to t  
{
    //find all arrays that start with f(take first array and add second element to current queue)  
    //if there are multiple arrays that start with f then duplicate queue and do the same as the first array  
    count++  
    //take second element of array and make it f  
    //if f = t then print queue + count  
    //else findshort(f,t,count)
    //run each queue through the "findshort" function again
}
```

Again this is just a VERY rough write up of what the program does so do not down-vote from how poorly done this all is. I would use a structure to keep track of the queues and another for the list of nodes. If you are wondering the file is as follows:

```
cat adj.data  
1 2  
2 3  
3 4  
2 5  
5 6  
6 3  
6 7  
4 8  
5 8  
8 1
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @igavriil I am mostly asking for help implementing this. I am just not sure how exactly to code it, all I really have is the general idea of what I want to do.